# Access 2013 Form / Oracle Backend App Running in Shared Drive

Tags: oracle, ms-access, odbc, database-connection

Question:

I have an MS Access form app that uses an Oracle backend.

The MS Access database files are physically on a file share that is on the same server where Oracle is running.

When I try to run the Access database front-end from the share, I get a connection error(3151).

It worked fine when the access front end was on my desktop (Oracle was able to establish a connection), but it can't when being run from a share. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is usually best practice to install the front-end on a users local hard drive.

If you are running the database on a different computer you may need to install the Oracle ODBC Driver and/or create a DSN file locally.

Please note the version of the Oracle ODBC driver needs to be the same as what was used to initially link the tables.

Comment: Thank You. I do have a Oracle ODBC Driver on the Client, but it doesn't seem to matter. Perhaps I should put it on the 'share' as well?

Comment: Did you create a DSN file on the development machine when linking the tables?  If so you will probably need to copy that across to the client machine or create a DSN less connection string

Comment: I created a DSN less connection string!

Comment: Have you tried manually creating a Microsoft Access linked table to the Oracle database from the client machine?

Comment: Thank you *very* much for suggesting I relink the tables. I did that, and got another error (2540) about not being able to find the query. I moved my oracle database connection function up to Form_Open (which is before Form_Load) and voila!, it worked. Thank you so much for guiding me in that direction! ;)